# jQuery script works only once, then TypeError: $(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've downloaded this script for use conditional fields in forms:

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.conditionize = function(options) {

    var settings = $.extend({
        hideJS: true
    }, options );

    $.fn.showOrHide = function(is_met, $section) {
      if (is_met) {
        $section.slideDown();
      }
      else {
        $section.slideUp();
        $section.find('select, input').each(function(){
            if ( ($(this).attr('type')=='radio') || ($(this).attr('type')=='checkbox') ) {
                $(this).prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
            }
            else{
                $(this).val('').trigger('change');
            }
        });
      }
    }

    return this.each( function() {
      var $section = $(this);
      var cond = $(this).data('condition');

      // First get all (distinct) used field/inputs
      var re = /(#?\w+)/ig;
      var match = re.exec(cond);
      var inputs = {}, e = "", name ="";
      while(match !== null) {
        name = match[1];
        e = (name.substring(0,1)=='#' ? name : "[name=" + name + "]");
        if ( $(e).length && ! (name in inputs) ) {
            inputs[name] = e;
        }
        match = re.exec(cond);
      }

      // Replace fields names/ids by $().val()
      for (name in inputs) {
        e = inputs[name];
        tmp_re = new RegExp("(" + name + ")\\b","g")
        if ( ($(e).attr('type')=='radio') || ($(e).attr('type')=='checkbox') ) {
          cond = cond.replace(tmp_re,"$('" + e + ":checked').val()");
        }
        else {
          cond = cond.replace(tmp_re,"$('" + e + "').val()");
        }
      }

      //Set up event listeners
      for (name in inputs) {
        $(inputs[name]).on('change', function() {
          $.fn.showOrHide(eval(cond), $section);
        });
      }

      //If setting was chosen, hide everything first...
      if (settings.hideJS) {
        $(this).hide();
      }
      //Show based on current value on page load
      $.fn.showOrHide(eval(cond), $section);
    });
  }
}(jQuery));
```

I'm trying this because I need to use conditionize() in one of my tabs and when I reload the tab, all works but if I go to other tab and I return to the previous tab(where I need this works), I get that error.

When I change tabs, I'm only reloading one part of the page.

When I load the page this works perfectly, but if I try to call function again from browser console, it tells me that `TypeError: $(...)conditionize() is not a function`.

I have included the script in header tag and I'm calling it with this script on the bottom of body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('.conditional').conditionize();
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

I have written

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log($('.conditional').conditionize);
    setTimeout(function () {console.log($('.conditional').conditionize);}, 2);
</script>
```

and this print me at console the function, and when 2 milliseconds have passed, it print me `undefined`

Comment: wrap it into $(document).ready(... where you call it

Comment: @daremachine I'm getting the same error

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){ $('.conditional').conditionize(); });` gives the same error?

Comment: @TimSeguine it gives the same error and doesn't work in the first load

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/whnmn8zo/2/ There must be some piece of the puzzle missing from your description.

Comment: @TimSeguine thanks for your replies but it still doesnt work. I have written `console.log($('.conditional').conditionize);
   setTimeout(function () {console.log($('.conditional').conditionize);}, 2);` and this print me at console the function, and when 2 milliseconds have passed, it print me undefined

Comment: try change the function name, may be cleaned from other scripts on your page. Or try function take it out and paste dirty to .load( function in your page if it will be initialized.

Comment: @daremachine Same error. I think I'm loosing the jQuery object or something like that, but I don't know how to see it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/whnmn8zo/4/ The only thing wrong with what you posted was already mentioned. I don't have a crystal ball. If you can't show us a reproducible problem, then all we can do is guess. That only wastes our time and yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

Because any reason, the $ object and jQuery object are not the same in my code.

I have discovered it using this on browser console:

`$===jQuery`

This return false (This was produced because in other JS, I was using the `noConflict()`, which give me the problem)

Explanation: [noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

So I have solved it changing the last line of my JS by:

```
//Show based on current value on page load
      $.fn.showOrHide(eval(cond), $section);
    });
  }
}($));
```

Putting the `$` instead of `'jQuery'`